# PHP populate formatted date (only month and year) into drop down list, but delete duplicates

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to get the dates from the DB, store only the months and years of them into a var, populate the drop drown list with the results, but delete any duplicate month and year.

For example my drop down list is displaying:

- Jun 14
- Jun 14
- Jul 14
- Aug 14
- Aug 14
- Aug 14
- Sep 14
- Jan 15
- Feb 15
- Jun 15
- Jun 15

And I only want it do to display one month (with year) each option.

Here's my code:

```
            <select name="month">
                <?php
                    $sSDate = "SELECT DISTINCT eventStartDate FROM te_events GROUP BY eventStartDate ORDER BY eventStartDate ASC";
                    $qrSDate = mysql_query($sSDate) or die (mysql_error());
                    while($rowSDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($qrSDate))
                    {
                        $s_event_start_date = $rowSDate ['eventStartDate'];

                        $sGetStartDate = strtotime($s_event_start_date);
                        $sFormattedStartDate = date('M y', $s_event_start_date );

                        echo '
                        <option value="'.$sFormattedStartDate.'">
                            '.$sFormattedStartDate.'
                        </option>
                        ';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: If your months and years are in their own field, you could use 'GROUP BY Month,year' in your query to limit the number of returns.  That seems the easiest way to me, but I would need to know how the data is laid out.

Comment: Your DISTINCT is for the date not the month+year.. So every date is a unique value.

Answer (score 2):

Use sql: Select distinct Year(eventStartDate), month(eventStartDate) from ...

Comment: Good call.  For whatever reason I didn't even think this far along.

Comment: So how would i format the month a date into variables ... ?

Comment: Date('M y',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year))

Comment: so where would i implement that into the code above ?

Comment: Read the php documentation, it would be easy